# Using Outdoor pavers stone for fireplace

Tags: fireplace, outdoor, stone

We are redoing our fireplace and I'm throwing the idea of using stone from the outdoor garden section for the floor base of the fireplace (approximately 12 sq ft worth). Any reasons it is a poor idea? What are the better stones for this ie ones that may not chip as easily?

Answer (score 5):

The characteristics and composition of firebrick also called refractory brick make it suitable for high heat applications. Conventional pavers will fail quickly when exposed to heat. I can't testify about pavers but I have had concrete explosively spall (small pieces of concrete shrapnel) while cutting steel anchors with a torch. So you really need bricks that are designed for use in a fireplace.